# What is the best and most efficient way to loop and test through an object of regexes

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

The aim of the code below is to loop through an object of regexes and test a provided link(url) against each regex in the `sites2embedRegex`  object. The current solution I have works, but my QUESTION is is there a better and more efficient way of writing this code? Thanks

```js
const sites2embedRegex = {
      a: /(((http:\/\/)?(instagr\.am\/p\/.*|instagram\.com\/p\/.*|(www\.)?instagram\.com\/p\/.*))|(https:\/\/((www\.)?instagram\.com\/p\/.*)))/i,
      b: /(((http:\/\/)?(lean-data-science\.com\/.*))|((https:\/\/)?(lean-data-science\.com\/.*)))/i,
      c: /(((http:\/\/)?(.*imgur\.com\/.*))|((https:\/\/)?(.*imgur\.com\/.*)))/i,
      d: /(((https?:\/\/)?((www\.)?flickr\.com\/photos\/.*|flic\.kr\/.*|img\.ly\/.*|giphy\.com\/gifs\/.*|gph\.is\/.*|media\.giphy\.com\/media\/.*|gist\.github\.com\/.*|play\.kotlinlang\.org\/embed#.*pl\.kotl\.in\/.*|(www\.)?slideshare\.net\/.*\/.*|(www\.)?slideshare\.net\/mobile\/.*\/.*|.*\.slideshare\.net\/.*\/.*|slidesha\.re\/.*|scribd\.com\/doc\/.*|(www\.)?scribd\.com\/doc\/.*|scribd\.com\/mobile\/documents\/.*|(www\.)?scribd\.com\/mobile\/documents\/.*|slidetosubscribe\.com\/.*|docdroid\.net\/.*|autodesk\.com\/.*|scrimba\.com\/.*|(www\.)?screencast\.com\/.*\/media\/.*|screencast\.com\/.*\/media\/.*|(www\.)?screencast\.com\/t\/.*|screencast\.com\/t\/.*|foursquare\.com\/.*|(www\.)?foursquare\.com\/.*|4sq\.com\/.*|maps\.google\.com\/maps\?.*|maps\.google\.com\/\?.*|maps\.google\.com\/maps\/ms\?.*|(www\.)?google\..*\/maps\/.*)))/i,
    }

 let embed = false;

 const link = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUpiE.jpg'
 const linkThatFails = 'https://imgur.com'

//loop throught each regex in the object while testing the provided link(url) against each regex;
 const res = Object.keys(sites2embedRegex).map(regex => sites2embedRegex[regex].test(link));
  
// loop through the resulting array to see if the link matches any of the regexes
 if(res.some(x => x === true)) { 
  embed = true; 
  return; 
 }
```

SAMPLE LINKS that can used to test the regex

> This url will pass - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUpiE.jpg
>
> This url will fail - https://imgur.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Array#map` at all; just use `Array#some`. This will return true the first time any regular expression matches, so you will not have to test all of them, which is very expensive.

```
if(Object.keys(sites2embedRegex).some(regex=>sites2embedRegex[regex].test(link))){
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, regex evaluation is an (usually) expensive operation so any optimisation you could make to accessory code would be meaningless **except** if it could avoid the (or some of them) regex evaluation itself.

That being said, it points out that your code is evaluating all regexes unconditionally and only after that it checks if at least one matched. So here you have the first possible optimisation.

Secondly, in ES6+, you could have used Object.entries() instead of Object.keys() and then address the original object (this optimizes nothing, but improves readability and could avoid bugs in some cases).

Then, as @hev1 already said, you can use `.some()` directly that will return at first match so, as I said at the beginning, if any of them matches, you avoid testing the rest.

Least but not last (pun intended), you can use a for loop instead of `.some()` / `.map()`, etc... to avoid extra function calls (if you need to test lots of simple regexes it may make sense, but otherwise not...).

And finally, you may better rely on a helper that may take care of all those possible cases, doing the job just fine and improving your the readability of your business code.

Here one of mine:

```
function multiMatch(rxs, target, debug = false) {//{{{                          
    if (! target) target = "";                                                  
    if (! (rxs instanceof Array)) rxs = [rxs];                                  
    for (let i=0; i<rxs.length; i++) {                                          
        let matches = target.match(rxs[i]);                                     
        if (matches) {                                                          
            if (debug) {                                                        
                console.log(i, rxs[i]);                                         
                console.log(matches);                                           
            };                                                                  
            return matches.slice(1);                                            
        };                                                                      
                                                                                
    };                                                                          
    if (debug) console.log("(No match)");                                       
    return [];                                                                  
};//}}}
```

> **Note:** This one also returns capture groups of first matching expression so, in your case, you would need to check for something
> like `multimatch(sites2embedRegex, link).length` (or just modify the
> helper for your taste).

**EDIT:** Nope. This helper is capturing focused and, if you pass it expressions without capture groups (or with capture groups that may not match even if the whole expression does) it will also return an empty array.

In your case you do need to modify it (or reactor it into a new one) to differentiate the non matching case.

To do so it would be enough to change the last `return []` statement by `return null`, for example.

> In my case, doing so would imply to call it as `multimatch(...) || []`
> that is not handy to me.